# How to fix gas-related errors in sending a transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, gas-limit, sendtransaction

I tried to make my first transaction but kept failing.
I searched here and there but still could not find a solution.
And came here to write a question.

I am trying to send some from `account[0]` to *other*.

I started geth as below with my `account[0]` (real address):

`Geth --syncmode full --miner.etherbase 'account[0] address' --nodiscover --cache 8192 console`

Then, typed the line below:

`eth.sendTransaction({ from:eth.accounts[0], to: _other account address_, value: web3.toWei(0.0015, "ether"), gas: 21000 } )`

Geth said:

> Error: exceeds block gas limit 
> at web3.js:6347:37(47) 
> at web3.js:5081:62(37) 
> at < eval>:1:20(20)

So I kept changing gas number and met this error with 5051:

> Error: intrinsic gas too low 
> at web3.js:6347:37(47)
> at web3.js:5081:62(37)
> at < eval>:1:20(20)

So it looks like the gas limit is set as 5051 but this is TOO LOW to start (or asking) my transaction.

Where can I change the gas limit?